# Restrict file creation inside Azure FileShare based on filenames

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I want to know if there is a way to set a policy/rule/restriction that only certain folders or files with specified approved names can be created within an Azure fileshare.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for File service share names are more restrictive than what is prescribed by the SMB protocol for SMB share names, so that the Blob and File services can share similar naming conventions for containers and shares. The naming restrictions for shares are as follows: Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata)

You may check here for [Azure RBAC permissions related to this configuration:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-configure-permissions)

You can check out my [Azure Policies for Naming conventions](https://github.com/DeanCefola/Azure-Policy/tree/master/Naming%20Conventions)

[Naming rules and restrictions for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftstorage)